# ZooKeeper Failover controller crashes when the Hadoop NameNode goes down

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, high-availability

We are setting up a Hadoop Cluster in our development environment. While we were testing the fail over of the NameNode we noticed that the Zookeeper Failover controller would sometimes crash.  In one case both ZooKeeper and the ZooKeeper Failover controller crashed.

At one point in our testing **both NameNodes** were in an **active** state.  This would cause a **split brain** scenario in the Hadoop Cluster.

We are using the following versions:
 - hadoop-2.7.3 
 - zookeeper-3.4.10

We have two a four server cluster.  Two of the servers are dedicated to  NameNode and two of the servers are dedicated to DataNodes.

The components running on the NameNode servers are
 - NameNode
 - ZooKeeper
 - ZooKeeper Failover controller
 - JournalNode

The components running on the DataNode servers are
 - DataNode
 - ZooKeeper
 - JournalNode

[The following matrix contains the test scenarios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odsVY.jpg)

Comment: Does ZKFC started in both nodes ? and post the zkfc.config file.